# ranking values wrt dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to rank my dictionary based on it's values. For example:

```
score = {'178413': 0.0, '178414': 0.0}
```

after operation should be

```
score = {'178413': 1.5, '178414': 1.5}
```

I tried

```
    import scipy.stats as ss
    temp = ss.rankdata(score.values())
    print temp
    temp = [1.5 1.5]`
```

So rank of the score.values is equal to temp. I want to replace the corresponding temp values back in the dictionary where values are placed
But can't seem to place it back in the dictionary.

**Complete code which i tried **

So following is the way , i am placing it back in the dictionary. I just feel it's not the correct

```
import scipy.stats as ss
score = {'178413': 3, '178414': 0.0}
inv_score = {y:x for x,y in score.iteritems()}
rank_val = ss.rankdata(score.values())

count = 0
for i in score.values():
    id = inv_score[i]
    score[id] = rank_val[count]
    count += 1
```

Output : score =  {'178413': 2.0, '178414': 1.0}

Code will fail if 
    input score was {'178413': 0.0, '178414': 0.0}

Comment: It is not at all clear to me how you think that the output corresponds to the input

Comment: edited my question. thanks

Comment: *"can't seem to place it back in the dictionary"* - what have you tried, and what happened? Note that lists are ordered but dictionaries aren't...

Comment: so once i have calculated the rank of the values of dictionary. I want to replace the values in the original dictionary to the respective rank

Comment: **"...what have you tried, and what happened?"** Please give a [mcve].

Comment: placed the example. thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90983/discussion-between-aditya-patel-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: @AdityaPatel what is the expected output

Comment: The expected output is the one i have shown but the code will fail if  score.values are all same. Code will fail if score = {'178413': 0.0, '178414': 0.0}

Comment: @AdityaPatel it is not clear what you are asking please be more specific why is  `score = {'178413': 2.0, '178414': 1.0}` what should be the value

Comment: Sorry what i mean is when dictionary values are all distinct , the code i have written works but suppose if they were not distinct than it would fail

Comment: @AdityaPatel could you change the data structure from `dictionary to list`

Comment: @VigneshKalai I tried a tuple. But i was not able to solve. Can you elaborate on it more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90985/discussion-between-vignesh-kalai-and-aditya-patel).